# How to send and receive a decimal array through serial port?

Tags: python, xbee

I'm trying to send an array `[0, 100, 150, 175, 255]` through serial in python. I convert it to bytearray then send it.

The data I'm receiving looks like

`['\x00', 'd', '\x96', '\xaf', '\xff']` and I can't go back to `[0, 100, 150, 175, 255]`.

Is there a better way to send and receive this kind of data? I'm new to python and I'm unfamiliar with some methods.

These are the codes I'm using.

SEND

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=10)
elements= [0,100,150,175,255]
data2=bytearray(elements)

while True:
      ser.write(data2)
```

RECEIVE

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=10)
vect = []

while True:
      vect.extend(ser.read())
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can go back to `[0, 100, 150, 175, 255]`! You're sending the data from a `bytearray`, and you should also use a `bytearray` to receive the data. To convert the received bytes back to integers, you just need to pass the `bytearray` to `list()`.

Here's a demo:

```
elements = [0, 100, 150, 175, 255]

# Buffer for sending data
data2 = bytearray(elements)

# Buffer for reading data
rdata = bytearray()

# Simulate sending data over the serial port
rdata.extend(data2[0:2])
rdata.extend(data2[2:5])

vect = list(rdata)
print(vect)
```

**output**

```
[0, 100, 150, 175, 255]
```

This code works correctly on both Python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

It can be tempting to use `eval()` here:

```
while True:
      vect = eval(ser.read().decode('unicode_escape'))
```

However, **don't** use it. It's generally bad to use `eval()`. I think @PM2Ring's answer is better.

Comment: @PM2Ring What's the problem with that?

Comment: `eval` should only be used when you have no other option. Not only is `eval` slow, `eval` and `exec` should generally be avoided because they can be a security risk. Passing arbitrary unsanitised data to `eval` is _extremely_ unsafe. For details, please see [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks. I'll check out that link. Should I delete this answer then?

Comment: Well, that's up to you, but it probably would be a good idea to delete it. OTOH, you can leave it here as a warning, showing how _not_ to do it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert the char you receive to int:

```
vect.extend([ord(ch) for ch in ser.read()])
```